# How to define arduino byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, byte

I trying to port over the following code:

```
byte DIV_3_OF_5[8] = {
  B11100, 
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100
}; // 3 / 5

byte DIV_4_OF_5[8] = {
  B11110, 
  B11110,
  B11110,
  B11110,
  B11110,
  B11110,
  B11110,
  B11110
}; // 4 / 5
```

What is the C syntax for this, and how to define 0s and 1s in this case? Do I need to convert the number to hex?

Answer (score 2):

C does not have binary literals so you will indeed need to convert the numbers to hex.

Which in this case is trivial: `0x1C` and `0x1E` respectively.

Comment: @nabil.douss Good universities force you to learn binary and hex before you are allowed to do any form of programming.

Comment: My mistake ! I learned hex and binary, just seeing 3 and then 4 made me think that they are successive numbers. With a closer look to the binary I got it :)

Comment: @Lundin 0x1c -> 0000 0000 0001 1100. This is not what I need. I have an array 8x5. All elements in the array have to be 5 bits long.

Comment: @munin24 Why? There are no 5 bit processors. And since you have tagged this Linux, it makes even less sense. Simply use `uint8_t`.